# Como pegar valor de variável dentro de uma function em uma Classe para outra function?

Tags: php, classes

Tenho uma classe para Upload de Imagens, e quero pegar o valor de uma variável dentro de uma `function` chamada `salvar()`!

Eu quero criar um função chamada `getNome()` para pegar o nome da imagem com extensão. Mas a variável com o nome da imagem está na função `salvar()`, como faço isso? E eu quero dar um `echo $nome_img;` para usar na hora do `insert` em um arquivo `.php`!

**ImgUpload.php**

```
<?php 

class Upload{
    private $arquivo;
    private $altura;
    private $largura;
    private $pasta;

    function __construct($arquivo, $altura, $largura, $pasta){
        $this->arquivo = $arquivo;
        $this->altura  = $altura;
        $this->largura = $largura;
        $this->pasta   = $pasta;
    }

    private function getExtensao(){
        //retorna a extensao da imagem
        return $extensao = strtolower(end(explode('.', $this->arquivo['name'])));
    }

    private function ehImagem($extensao){
        $extensoes = array('gif', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'png');     // extensoes permitidas
        if (in_array($extensao, $extensoes))
            return true;
    }

    //largura, altura, tipo, localizacao da imagem original
    private function redimensionar($imgLarg, $imgAlt, $tipo, $img_localizacao){
        //descobrir novo tamanho sem perder a proporcao
        if ( $imgLarg > $imgAlt ){
            $novaLarg = $this->largura;
            $novaAlt = round( ($novaLarg / $imgLarg) * $imgAlt );
        }
        elseif ( $imgAlt > $imgLarg ){
            $novaAlt = $this->altura;
            $novaLarg = round( ($novaAlt / $imgAlt) * $imgLarg );
        }
        else // altura == largura
            $novaAltura = $novaLargura = max($this->largura, $this->altura);

            //redimencionar a imagem

            //cria uma nova imagem com o novo tamanho
            $novaimagem = imagecreatetruecolor($novaLarg, $novaAlt);

            switch ($tipo){
                case 1: // gif
                    $origem = imagecreatefromgif($img_localizacao);
                    imagecopyresampled($novaimagem, $origem, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                            $novaLarg, $novaAlt, $imgLarg, $imgAlt);
                    imagegif($novaimagem, $img_localizacao);
                    break;
                case 2: // jpg
                    $origem = imagecreatefromjpeg($img_localizacao);
                    imagecopyresampled($novaimagem, $origem, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                            $novaLarg, $novaAlt, $imgLarg, $imgAlt);
                    imagejpeg($novaimagem, $img_localizacao);
                    break;
                case 3: // png
                    $origem = imagecreatefrompng($img_localizacao);
                    imagecopyresampled($novaimagem, $origem, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                            $novaLarg, $novaAlt, $imgLarg, $imgAlt);
                    imagepng($novaimagem, $img_localizacao);
                    break;
            }

            //destroi as imagens criadas
            imagedestroy($novaimagem);
            imagedestroy($origem);
    }


    public function salvar(){
        $extensao = $this->getExtensao();

        //gera um nome unico para a imagem em funcao do tempo
         $novo_nome = time() . '.' . $extensao;
        //localizacao do arquivo
        $destino = $this->pasta . $novo_nome;

        //move o arquivo
        if (! move_uploaded_file($this->arquivo['tmp_name'], $destino)){
            if ($this->arquivo['error'] == 1)
                return "Tamanho excede o permitido";
                else
                    return "Erro " . $this->arquivo['error'];
        }

        if ($this->ehImagem($extensao)){
            //pega a largura, altura, tipo e atributo da imagem
            list($largura, $altura, $tipo, $atributo) = getimagesize($destino);

            // testa se é preciso redimensionar a imagem
            if(($largura > $this->largura) || ($altura > $this->altura))
                $this->redimensionar($largura, $altura, $tipo, $destino);
        }
        return "Sucesso";
    }

    public function getNome() {

        echo $novo_nome;

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Coloque o conteúdo da classe.

Comment: ok tudo bem, editando........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Poderia apenas declarar uma nova propriedade para a classe.

Pode ser declarada como privada.

Um exemplo genérico:

```
class Test{
    private $foo;
    
    public function A() {
        $this->foo = 'bar';
    }
    
    public function B() {
        return $this->foo;
    }
}

$c = new Test;
$c->A();
echo $c->B();
```

## Para o seu caso específico

**Declarando a propriedade**

```
class Upload{
    private $arquivo;
    private $altura;
    private $largura;
    private $pasta;
    private $novo_nome; // declare aqui como private
```

**O método salvar()**:

```
public function salvar(){
    $extensao = $this->getExtensao();

    //gera um nome unico para a imagem em funcao do tempo
     $this->novo_nome = time() . '.' . $extensao;
    //localizacao do arquivo
    $destino = $this->pasta . $this->novo_nome;
```

**O método getNome()**

```
public function getNome() {

    echo $this->novo_nome;

}
```

Comment: ow cara funcionou perfeito obrigado, é porque eu nunca me aprofundei quando o assunto é classe!